# How to preserve a list or a dict in python recursive function?

Tags: python

I have to use a recursive function in python, code below is a simplified model.
I want to preserve result list and dict dictionary not generate a new list or dictionary while in the recursive, and return it after recursive, how to solve it?

```
def test(length):
    result = []
    dict = {}
    if length == 10:
        return result, dict
    else:
        result.append(length)
        dict[length] = length + 1
        test(length + 1)

x, y = test(0)
print x, y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper function that performs the recursion, and the main function to call the helper with the initial defaults.

```
def test(length):
    result = []
    dict = {}
    _test(length, result, dict)
    return result, dict

def _test(length, result, dict):
    if length == 10:
        return
    else:
        result.append(length)
        dict[length] = length + 1
        _test(length + 1, result, dict)

x, y = test(0)
print x, y
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, _test(length + 1) should be _test(length + 1, result, dict)

Answer (score 1):

I think your recursion is slightly broken.

Python offers some other options for doing exactly what you want to do. I like this format:

```
def t(length, result = [], d = {}):
    if length == 10:
        return
    else:
        result.append(length)
        d[length] = length + 1
        t(length + 1)

    return (result, d)

x, y = t(0)
print x, y
```

The initialization of the arrays and dictionaries only happen when the function is seen by the interpreter, not every time you call the function. See this [page](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) for a good introduction to the default parameters in python.

In this case, they act like arrays and dictionaries that are attached to the function.